# Are these lines perpendicular - 3 dimensional parametric equations

Tags: calculus, vectors

I was given a problem asking to state whether or not two given lines were perpendicular of parallel, and to find the angle between them. These are lines in 3 dimensional space, and are defined by parametric equations. Here is a picture of one of the problems:

[image]

Do I need to test these by checking their dot product and cross product? How do I find that if I have an equation not a vector? (I know I need to include my work - just I've been trying to work this problem and haven't gotten anywhere. I really don't know how to do it. )

Comment: check the dot product and cross product of $(-3,4,1)$ and $(2,-2,1)$ to check if the lines are perpendicular or parallel

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Why did you choose those two vectors? I see that they are the coefficients of t and s, but why does that work?

Comment: they are vectors with the directions of the lines; you could find the angle $\theta$ between them using the relationship between dot product and $\cos \theta$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner what do you mean when you say they are the vectors with the directions of the lines?

Comment: Thanks for all your help - this is really helping me!

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142756/what-is-vector-equation-of-line) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976812/how-to-find-line-parallel-to-direction-vector-and-passing-through-a-specific-poi)